# How do you lean mixture using only the instruments on a C172 Skyhawk?

Tags: piston-engine, fuel-systems, cessna-172, mixture

POH manuals always tells to use the voice of the engine as a reference. (Which complicates things a little bit since carbs and fuel injected planes have different "reaction times" for each cylinder)

But how do you lean the mixture without using your ears? How do you lean mixture with only the instruments as a guide?

Lets assume we have a brand new C172 Skyhawk

Comment: Depends what instruments you have... Does it have a CHT? Single or per cylinder temp gauge? Manifold pressure gauge? Or just tach? It's actually really easy to tell by paying attention to the engine. As you lean it out the engine will noticably get rougher.

Comment: @RonBeyer lets assume a brand new C172 skyhawk

Comment: http://www.sweetaviation.com/leaning-procedures/

Comment: Related: [What appears on EGT Gauge if the mixture is rich or lean?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21466/14897)

Comment: Are new C172s fuel injected? They could in theory run Lean of Peak for lower fuel burn & cooler cylinders if the injectors are evenly matched.

Comment: @CrossRoads I remember all 172S and 172SPs being fuel injected. Correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure varies depending on the engine instruments in the panel. Here’s an good [explanation](https://youtu.be/LaRpVJTpA3A) using the EGT probe on a Cessna 172.

And here are the manual pages from a Cessna 172SP that explains it.

[[image: Lean Cessna 172SP - 1[2]]

[image: Lean Cessna 172SP - 2]